# Sorting points according to their coordinates

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, contour

In my software I get points of a 2D contour stored in a vector `matrix`
My task now is to sort this points so I get the contour. First I tried the `atan2` function, witch worked good for regular cases. But in cases for a non convex contour this do not work.
So after a look up in google and after some replies here, I now try to calculate the nearest points. So therfore I have a function that calculates the distance between two points.

```
double distancepoints(vector<double> const& s1, vector<double> const& s2)
{
    return sqrt( (s1[0] - s2[0])*(s1[0] - s2[0]) + (s1[1] - s2[1])*(s1[1] - s2[1]) );
}
```

To find the nearest point I would define in a function the index of the point, which is closest to a predetermined starting point.

```
int closestpoint(vector<double> const& p, begin, end )
{
   double d=0;
   result = begin;
   while(begin != end)
   {
      double d2 = distancepoints(p, begin);
      if(d2 < d)
      {
        d = d2;
        result = begin;
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here I do not know how I to pass the beginn and the end of the vector.

If I have the index of the next point, I would save this point in the vector `Hull` and delete it from the vector `matrix`. This should happen as long, until the `matrix` completely erased.

```
vector<vector<double> > matrix;
vector<vector<double> > hull;

int columns = 3;

const std::vector<LineSegment> &lss = slicesWithLineSegments[i];
rows = 2*lss.size();

matrix.resize(rows);

for(size_t i=0; i<matrix.size(); i++) {
    matrix[i].resize(columns);
}

for(size_t i=0; i<hull.size(); i++) {
    hull[i].resize(columns);
}

vector<vector<double> > startpoint;

for(size_t i=0; i<startpoint.size(); i++) {
    startpoint[i].resize(columns);
}

startpoint[0][0]=matrix[0][0];
startpoint[0][1]=matrix[0][1];
startpoint[0][2]=matrix[0][2];

matrix.erase(matrix.begin() );

while (matrix.size())
{
// Find next point (the one closest to p) and return index
int it = closestpoint( startpoint, matrix.begin(), matrix.end() );

// Store nearest point 
hull.push_back(std::vector<double>(3, 0));
r = hull.size()-1;
hull[r][0] = matrix[it][0];
hull[r][1] = matrix[it][1];
hull[r][2] = matrix[it][2];
// Our new p is the point we just found
startpoint = matrix[it];
// Remove the point we just found from the vector of points
matrix.erase(matrix[it]);
}
```

But somehow I manage not just to program the function. Maybe someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose `matrix.erase(it)` instead of `matrix.erase(matrix[it])`

Comment: @max66: Thanks for the tip. But my main problem is in the function `closestpoint`. Here I don't know how I could make this function working, so it returns the index of the nearest point to a starting point.

Comment: Given `vector<vector<double> > it;

    for(size_t i=0; i<it.size(); i++) {
        it[i].resize(columns);
}` the for loop does nothing because `it.size()` is necessarily zero.  Also your `closestpoint` function takes one argument but you call it with three!  (I think the call is closer to what you actually want).  Please can you sort your code out, and try and post a [mcve].

Comment: What type is matrix? Maybe `std::vector<std::vector<double>>::const_iterator` is the type you need, but its just an assumption.

Comment: I suggest you do something like `typedef std::array<double,3> Point;` and then you can have vectors of Points in a sensible manner.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I edited the question. my main problem is the function `closestpoint`. I do not know how I could pass the beginning and the end of my vector matrix to this fanction and how to return the index. So it's hard for me to post a example of the code.

Comment: what does the declaration of `distancepoints` look like?  (I am assuming it is a pre-existing function.)

Comment: Sorry - just seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I am writing for a C++11 compatible compiler. So >> is perfectly valid for templates ;)

**First**

A vector of vectors is a very inefficient way of storing threedimensional data. You should consider using

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>
```

instead of

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>>
```

I am using std::array for the examples. If you need std::vector for a single point just use this type instead of std::array

**Second**

You do not need to calculate the square root if you search for the nearst point. Comparing the square distance will work.

```
double squareDistancePoints(const std::array<double, 3>& a, const std::array<double, 3>& b)
{
    return pow(a[0]-b[0], 2) + pow(a[1]-b[1], 2) + pow(a[2]-b[2], 2);
}
```

For vector-points this would be

```
double squareDistancePoints(const std::vector<double>& a, const std::vector<double>& b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    double sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        sum += pow(a[i]-b[i], 2);
    return sum;
}
```

**Third**

If you delete used points from your 'matrix', why will you supply begin and end iterators to your 'closestpoint' function?

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>::const_iterator closestPoint(const std::array<double, 3>& point, const std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>& matrix)
{
    return std::min_element(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [=](const auto& a, const auto& b) { 
        return squareDistancePoints(point, a) < squareDistancePoints(point, b); 
    });
}
```

So you do not need the closestPoint() function at all. What you need is std::min_element from the standard library. It's a little bit slower this way because the distance for the best point is calculated multiple times, but if your sqrt() was fast enough, this code will also be fast enough.

A faster, but longer version is here:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>::const_iterator closestPoint(const std::array<double, 3>& point, const std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>& matrix)
{
    double bestDistance = DBL_MAX;
    auto bestIt = matrix.end();

    for(auto it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it)
    {
        const auto distance = squareDistancePoints(point, *it);
        if (distance < bestDistance)
        {
            bestDistance = distance;
            bestIt = it;
        }  
    }

    return bestIt;
}
```

**Example**

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> matrix;
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> hull;

... // populate matrix

// Add first point to hull
hull.push_back(matrix.back());
matrix.pop_back();

// Add additional points to hull
while(!matrix.empty())
{
    auto it = closestPoint(hull.back(), matrix);
    hull.push_back(*it);
    matrix.erase(it);
}
```

**Inline Example**
without using closestPoint() function because this *would* require a closestPoint() function which takes begin and end iterator.

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> points;

... // populate points with matrix data

for(auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
{
    auto bestIt = points.end();
    double bestSquareDistance = DBL_MAX;
    for(auto nextIt = it + 1; nextIt != points.end(); ++nextIt)
    {
        const auto squareDistance = squareDistancePoints(*it, *nextIt);
        if (squareDistance < bestSquareDistance)
        {
             bestSquareDistance = squareDistance;
             bestIt = nextIt;
        }
    }
    if (bestIt != points.end())
        std::swap(*(it+1), *bestIt);
}
```

**Short Inline Example**
(Short, but very inefficient; Useable for small sets of points)

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> points;

... // populate points with matrix data

for(auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end() && it+1 != points.end(); ++it)
    std::sort(it+1, points.end(), [=](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return squareDistancePoints(*it, a) < squareDistancePoints(*it, b);
    });

// vector 'points' now contains all hull points in correct order
```

**Full Example**
I created a small sample program which sorts the points of a 2D rectangle. You can find it at http://ideone.com/OeCpdG

Comment: Thanks for the help. My idea was, I have to delete the used points from `matrix`, so that I can not visit again. By deleting I prevent a continuous loop in which I jump back and forth repeatedly between two points. I thank you for the `std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>` tip.

Comment: To use our closestPoint function I would use it=closestPoint() in the while (matrix.size()) loop? Did I get this correct?

Comment: Many thanks for your example. One last question. In the line ` std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> matrix; std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> hull;' I get the error message: `'array' : is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include the array header.

Comment: I tried to use your example, but in the line `const auto squareDistance = squareDistancePoints(*it, *nextIt);` I get the message `cannot convert parameter 1 from std::array<_Ty,_Size> to const std::vector<_Ty> & `.. I also tried to change the parameters form vector to array, but this also didn't worked

Comment: If you declare `std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> points;` each element in the points vector is of type `std::array<double, 3>` so dereferencing an iterator to this vector (`*it` or `*nextIt` for example) creates a value of this type so you need a squareDistancePoints() function which takes two `std::array<double, 3>` parameters but it seems that you only implemented the version with `std::vector<double>` (at least this would explain the compiler message). - 
Implement `double squareDistancePoints(const std::array<double, 3>& a, const std::array<double, 3>& b)` and it should work.

Comment: I used your Inline Example to test my code. But it seems the code is ignoring that section. So I edited my vector to `std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> matrix;` and fill it as always. To test it I print the unsorted points to a csv file. Then I use your code but instead of points I use matrix. I didn't change anything in your code. When I print out the now sorted points, I get exact the same ordering as before. Here is my code [link](http://ideone.com/bOlT1r) . Can you figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please use `double bestSquareDistance = DBL_MAX;` instead of initializing bestSquareDistance to 0.0. This is a bug in my code (already fixed it with an edit). You may set a breakpoint at the std::swap() call. If it is hit, the result must be different from the source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112794/discussion-between-andreas-h-and-user3794592).

Answer (score 0):

So let us add some typedefs to simplify the code:

```
typedef std::vector<double> Point;   // I still think std::array<double,3>
                                     // would be better here.
typedef std::vector<Point> PointList;

size_t closestpoint( const Point& p, const PointList& plist)
{
    if (plist.empty())
    {
        throw ???;  // Call is meaningless if plist is empty.
    }
    size_t result = 0;
    double best = distancepoints( p, plist[result] );
    for (size_t i = 1; i < plist.size(); i++)
    {
         const double dist = distancepoints( p, plist[i] );
         if (dist < best)
         {
             result = i;
             best = dist;
         }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

The call is:

```
    size_t it = closestpoint(startpoint, matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. One think I don't get is how to call your `closestpoint' function in the `while`-loop. I understand that I should use std::array, so do I have just change the definition of `vector <vector <double>> matrix` to` std :: array <double, 3> matrix; `? And how do I call this function in the while loop?

Comment: No.  It would be `vector<array<double,3>> matrix;` or `vector<Point> matrix;` (which makes what is happening even clearer).

Answer (score 0):

I propose (caution: not tested)

```
int closestpoint (std::vector<std::vector<double> > const & p,
                  std::vector<std::vector<double> >::const_iterator & it, 
                  std::vector<std::vector<double> >::const_iterator & end )
{
   double d=DBL_MAX;
   int  result=0;
   for (int i = 0 ; it != end ; ++it, ++i)
   {
      double d2 = distancepoints(p, *it);
      if(d2 < d)
      {
        d      = d2;
        result = i;
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When I try your code I get: `'closestpoint' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'` . The call of the function looks like this `int it = closestpoint(startpoint, matrix.begin(), matrix.end());`

Comment: @user3794592 - sorry: I didn't changed the type of the first parameter; I suppose should be `std::<std::vector<double> > const & p`; I'll correct my answer